# I can't see my programs icons on the bar?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-8-upgrade, windows-8.1-upgrade

I just got new **windows 8.1 Update** yesterday.

But now, I can't see programs little icons on **task bar** ?

[image]

Could anyone tell me whats wrong with my OS?
Thank you.

All about metro apps (screenshot):

[image]

Comment: Those are *supposed* to be metro UI icons being pinned to your desktop. Try unpinning and pinning again.

Comment: Thanks for fast replay but i did. @NathanC nothing didn't change.

Comment: You show highlighting there - does the button actually function, you just the icon is not displayed?

Comment: yes @ernie no icons with metro apps. here is the all apps screen shot : http://i.imgur.com/oaTcfJl.png

Comment: Maybe try deleting the icon cache (hidden file at %userprofile%\AppData\Local\IconCache.db) and restarting explorer.exe (right click on the process in Task Manager and select Restart)?  This will force the cache to rebuild . . .

Comment: did not work @ernie :/

Comment: no more idea ? :(